# Is there a characterization of Riemannian manifolds that split off two factors?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Some Riemannian manifolds are expressed as a product manifold. Recently, I have read two articles about space-times. In both articles, the authors prove that a Riemannian manifold $\bar{M}^n$ is expressed as a product of the form $\mathbb R\times M^{n-1}$ i.e. the manifold splits off a factor $\mathbb{R}$. Both authors use similar techniques, namely integrable distribution, in this decomposition. Really, I do not understand this technique. Also, there are many splitting theorems in the literature of the same form, I mean $\mathbb R\times M^{n-1}$.

For me, it is enough to know a characterization of Riemannian manifolds $M^{n+m}$ which we can express them as a product manifold $M_1^n\times M_2^m$.

**Q1** Does this characterization exist?

**Q2** What conditions could one use to characterize these manifolds?

Note:

I asked the same question 2 days ago on Mathematics Stack exchange, I have got neither answer nor comment.

Comment: de Rham decomposition, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28040/de-rham-decomposition-theorem-generalisations-and-good-references

Comment: @littlelittlelittle Thank you very much. The de Rham decomposition theorem has some difficulties for me like "a tangent bundle is parallel to Levi-Civita connection" and "decomposition of tangent bundle" itself. I am looking for conditions on manifold curvature and topology etc. But now I have a way to keep me up. I will track the progress in this theorem to get an answer.

Comment: One more thing, I have read a comment of Richard Bishop on research gate says "All of the complete simply-connected constant-curvature spaces are warped products: Euclidean spaces are direct products of Euclidean spaces; de-Sitter space is $-R \times_{\cosh} S^3$ and the constant curvature sphere can be written $[-\pi/2,\pi/2] \times_{\cos} S^2$, etc."!!! Also, I will try to find a reference for this statement to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ralf Ponge and Helmut Reckziegel have show in their paper: "Twisted products in pseudo-Riemannian geometry" Geometriae Dedicata, October 1993, Volume 48, Issue 1, pp 15-25, the following result

Let $(M,g)$ be a simply connected psudo-Riemannian manifold with two complementary 
foliations $L$ and $K,$ whose leaves intersect perpendiculary. If the leaves of
$L$ are totally geodesic and geodesically complete and the leaves of $K$ are totally geodesic, then $(M,g)$ is isometric to a Riemmannian product, $(M_1\times M_2,g_1\oplus g_2),$ sucht that $L$ and $K$ correspond to the canonical foliations of the product.

Even more, they gave conditions on the foliations $L$ and $K$ in order to $(M,g)$ to be isometric to a twisted product (leaves of $L$ totally geodesic and leaves of $K$ totally umbilical) or a warped product (leaves of $L$ totally geodesic and leaves of $K$ extrinsic spheres).

Comment: If $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold, then this is the de Rham decomposition theorem.